# Regex with grep - match unknown number of alphabetical characters?

Tags: regex, grep, cygwin

I am searching for something like:

```
STRINGONE_****_******_STRINGTWO
```

Where I know STRINGONE and STRINGTWO. The *** reflect an unknown number of letters (capital), however.

I had been under the assumption

```
grep -nr "STRINGONE_\w+_\w+_STRINGTWO" .
```

would work, but I am not finding matches.

How can I formulate this regex correctly (using grep in cygwin)?

Comment: You say "characters", but `\w` is a notation (in various regex notations) for a specific subset of characters, usually `[0-9A-Za-z_]`. Can you clarify your intent?

Comment: @ruakh sorry. I clarified, I mean letters

Comment: Try escaping the `+` or using the `-E` flag. I think otherwise you have "basic" regex usage, where most of the meta-characters need to be escaped to *obtain* their special meaning.

Comment: @m.buettner `grep -nr "STRINGONE_\w\+_\w\+_STRINGTWO" .` works, great - thanks!

Comment: nice, I made it an answer ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Have a look at the manual.](http://www.gnu.org/software/grep/manual/html_node/Basic-vs-Extended.html#Basic-vs-Extended) Without the `-E` flag, `grep` assumes "basic" regular expressions. In this case most meta-characters lose their special meaning, *unless* you escape them. So do

```
grep -nr "STRINGONE_\w\+_\w\+_STRINGTWO"
```

or

```
grep -nrE "STRINGONE_\w+_\w+_STRINGTWO"
```

Or, since you only want uppercase letters:

```
grep -nr "STRINGONE_[A-Z]\+_[A-Z]\+_STRINGTWO"
grep -nrE "STRINGONE_[A-Z]+_[A-Z]+_STRINGTWO"
```

Otherwise, strings with three or more components in the middle would also be accepted.